# Model "Question" uses unknown mixin: Time

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, loopbackjs, mixins

I defined a mixin in my loopback v3 application but I got this error:

```
Model "Question" uses unknown mixin: Time
```

model-config.json :

```
 "mixins": [
  "loopback/common/mixins",
  "loopback/server/mixins",
  "../common/mixins",
  "./mixins"
]
```

question.json :

```
"mixins": {
  "Time": {
    "arg":"text"
  }
}
```

my mixin file name:

```
Time.js (in ./common/mixins folder)
```

Time.js code :

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (Model, options) {
    console.log("OK");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.By changing the mixin file name to time.js (lowercase) and mixin name in question.json to "Time" (Uppercase) it works perfectly.